# regarding tf.variable_scope(_DECODER_SCOPE, _DECODER_SCOPE, ...)

Tags: tensorflow

In this [program](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/model.py), there is one code segment

```
with tf.variable_scope(_DECODER_SCOPE, _DECODER_SCOPE, [features]):
        feature_list = feature_extractor.networks_to_feature_maps[
            model_variant][feature_extractor.DECODER_END_POINTS]
        if feature_list is None:
          tf.logging.info('Not found any decoder end points.')
          return features
        else:
```

I am not clear how to understand the the `tf.variable_scope` with those three arguments, what do that used for, why we need two `_DECODER_SCOPE` in the argument list?

Answer (score 0):

The second [argument to `variable_scope`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4b390bffbcb01d8f57f25c007277d457f752a69/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L1914) is a "default" name which gets uniquified (by appending a number). But it is only used if the first argument is `None`, so I believe that line is equivalent to:

`with tf.variable_scope('decoder', values=[features]):`

i.e. opening a `variable_scope` with the name `'decoder'`. [The `values` argument to `variable_scope` is explained in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40165610/6824418)